# What is a good way to show that PDE is linear

Tags: linear-pde

I just entering new world called Partial Differential Equations , now i just start with Classification PDE , in my Stanley J. Farlow's Text book there are six classification of PDE . But now I little bit struggle with *linear or non-linear* PDE

*Second  Order Linear Equation* in two variables is PDE can be written in the form 
$$Au_{xx}+Bu_{xy}+Cu_{yy}+Du_{x}+Eu_{y}+Fu=G$$

So , when i face with PDE like $u_{t}=\alpha^{2}u_{xx}$
i can identify its *linear* by saying it can be written as general form above with $A=\alpha^{2},B=0,C=0,D=0,E=-1,F=0$

but what if i face with some PDE with higher order let say 
*The Vibrating Beam  Equation*  $u_{tt}+u_{xxxx}=0$ ?

If i must identify this equation like the previous one , i really need a massive variable in general form , is there other good way to show that PDE is linear ?

Comment: You can think of a linear PDE as one in which derivatives of the independent variable u are not multiplied together or raised to powers other than $1$ like say $u u_x$ or $(u_{xx})^2$. So your beam equation has no non-linear terms and has a highest order derivative of $4$, so it is a linear fourth order PDE

Comment: @Triatticus $u$ is the **dependent** variable, not independent.

Comment: Yes that's right I was definitely abusing the terminology there

Answer (score 2):

To add to Batman's answer: If we consider the vector space of smooth functions $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ recall that the partial derivatives
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} : C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) \to C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)
$$
are linear transformations since given $f,g\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{R}$ we have that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} (\alpha f + \beta g) = \alpha \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} + \beta \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i} 
$$
Also, note that multiplication by a smooth function
$$
\cdot f: C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) \to C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)
$$
is a linear transformation. Since we can compose linear transformations to get a new linear transformation, we should call PDE's described via linear transformations **linear PDE's**. So, for your example, you are considering solutions to the kernel of the differential operator (another name for linear transformation)
$$
D = \frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4} + \frac{\partial}{\partial t^2}
$$
You can take this further. For example, solutions to the pde
$$
cos(x)u_{ttt} - u_y
$$
corresponds to the operator
$$
D = \cos(x)\frac{\partial^3}{\partial t^3} - \frac{\partial}{\partial y}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have two arbitrary solutions of the PDE, $u$ and $v$. Then, if you can show that for any scalar $\alpha$ that $u+\alpha v$ is also a solution, the PDE is linear.

In your vibrating beam equation, you have $u_{tt} + u_{xxxx} =0$ and $v_{tt} + v_{xxxx} =0$. Then, $(u+\alpha v)_{tt} + (u+\alpha v)_{xxxx} = u_{tt} + \alpha v_{tt} + u_{xxxx} + \alpha v_{xxxx} = (u_{tt} + u_{xxxx}) + \alpha (v_{tt} + v_{xxxx}) = 0 + \alpha (0) = 0$, so the PDE is indeed linear. The first step is simply linearity of (partial) derivatives, then some rearrangement and using the assumption that $u,v$ satisfy the PDE.

Comment: aaaah this is what i looking for , thanks for amazing explanation

Comment: This is the definition of linearity.